# How to remove URI extra slash when I converted NSUrl to URI

Tags: c#, ios, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, .net-core-2.1

When I am trying to convert NSUrl to URI added an extra slash in the URL below is the method

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
{
Uri uri = new Uri(url.AbsoluteString);
ViewController.Auth?.OnPageLoading(uri);
return true;
}
```

Output: `uri=msauth.com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx://auth/?code=ae49c2974f4a5ce7becc6ccc95ef98ac8c93cd314aeda9b46254e6f0e6f80957&scope=TriggerApi%20offline_access&state=dshrscvaicthdifb`

excepted result:  `uri=msauth.com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx://auth?code=ae49c2974f4a5ce7becc6ccc95ef98ac8c93cd314aeda9b46254e6f0e6f80957&scope=TriggerApi%20offline_access&state=dshrscvaicthdifb`

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to remove only the trailing slash, you can try using `uri = uri.TrimEnd('/');`
I have tested in my local environment, and was able to remove the slash using  `uri = uri.TrimEnd('/');`
[image]

Comment: Above solutions, I have tried but removing slash last character in the string but we need to change the URI object I have changed my output URL @SuryasriKamini-MT